# Curly braces in url cause a bad request error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

Curly braces for Play 2 has special meaning, and if they used in the url 
like

```
http://domain.com/?utm={utm}
```

Then framework returns error:

```
For request 'GET /?utm={utm}' [Illegal character in query at index 6: /?utm={utm}]
```

Does framework have a way, how to preprocess url and escape those

braces, or at least intercept error to send a notification about it?

Comment: What version of play are you on. It looks from [this bug report](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6066) that the issue is being attended to.

Comment: My version is 2.5.9

Comment: Doesn't look Play-specific to me. You need to URL encode those curly braces. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/curly-brackets-in-urls

Comment: Yeah, it is netty issue. It is not possible to handle this on the framework level.